# Regular Expression to match different script tags in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to match different script tags which
for example like this

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
    jQuery("#gift_cards").tooltip({ effect: \'slide\'});
 });
 </script>
 <script>dasdfsfsdf</script>
```

Also i need to get the tags only and the src content in groups
I created a regex

```
(<\s*?script[\s\S]*?(?:src=['"](\S+?)['"])?\B[\S\s]*?>)([\s\S]*?)(</script>)
```

This is not matching the last script tag

Whats wrong with it?

EDIT:
Removing the \B does match all the script tags but then i donot get the contents of the src attribute in a separate group. What I need to do is from a group of script tags of two categories

1. One with an src attribute with the path to the actual script
2. Second without src attribute with normal inline javascript

I need to remove the script opening and closing tags but keep the content inside of the tag
If its of the first type I still need to remove the tags but keep the path in a seperate table
Hope that clarifies it much more

Comment: *"Whats wrong with it?"* - See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2555451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that I agree with all the remarks about not parsing HTML with RegExp and also provided that I myself indulge in such evil practice when I'm confident that the documents I will process are regular enough, try removing the `\B`, in my test it matches all three scripts.

What is for, by the way, this "non boundary"? I'm not sure I understood why you inserted it. If it was necessary for some reason I do not grasp please tell me and we'll try to find another way.

Edit:
In order to retain the src content try

```
(<\s*?script[\s\S]*?(?:(?:src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"])(?:[\S\s]*?))?>)([\s\S]*?)(</scrip‌​t>)
```

This works for me, check against your other samples.
Consider that your `first [\s\S]*?` already matches everything till `>` when you do not have a "src" attribute, so the second one only makes sense if "src" is there and you want to match other possible attributes.

Comment: Edited with more info, please check

Comment: Thanks Your edit does retain the src contents but doesn't match the script tags without the src tags

Comment: Damn.. I forgot a ? to make the "src..." match optional. I have edited the RegEx, try now.

Comment: Thanks that works with a slight modification. With your regex i python says *** error: nothing to repeat
if i remove a "?" it works, the final working regex is (<\s*?script[\s\S]*?(?:(?:src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"])(?:[\S\s]*?))?>)([\s\S]*?)(</script>)

Comment: Doh.. I did not test it in Python but using the RegEx_Helper plugin in Notepad++ where I didn't need to escape the quote. Thanks for the correction, I have also adjusted the answer to match the working version.

Answer (score 3):

As iCodez' [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2555451) so entertainingly shows, HTML should not be parsed by regex, as HTML is not a regular language. Instead, try using a parser such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Make sure you also install [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and [`html5lib`](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) as well for best performance and access to all the features.

```
pip install lxml html5lib beautifulsoup4
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Actually I don't need to parse the full html but only script tags of two categories one with src and one without, wouldn't it be specific enough to be parsed by Regex?

Comment: don't parse html with regex.. use an html parser

Comment: @Shaumux it may be, it may not be. BeautifulSoup has excellent documentation, and it is much easier to parse something like this than to try regex after regex to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

For giggles, here's a super-simple way that I figured out by complete accident (as a js string which would be fed to the RegExp constructor:

'src=(=|=")' + yourPathHere + '[^<]<\/script>'

where yourPathHere has had forward slashes escaped; so, as a pure RE, something like:

/src=(=|=")/scripts/someFolder/script.js[^<]</script>/

which I'm using in a gulp task whilst I'm trying to figure out gulp streams :[]